# Got a syntax error after an attempt to create tables in MySQL but all should be correct I think

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I think that the syntax is correct, but when I am trying to create that tables I get syntax errors:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `img` TEXT NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `customer_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `product_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `grade` ENUM('Wspaniała', 'Dobra', 'Taka sobie', 'Zła', 'Bardzo zła') NOT NULL,
    `content` TEXT NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Errors:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMEN' at line 10

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
' at line 10

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-
-
-

CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCRE' at line 1
```

Do You maybe know what I am doing wrong?
Thank You.

Comment: Any syntax errors that you get should be added to the question as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, they are now added.

Comment: These SQL statements are correct itself. I think that the problem source is in the method which you use for these statements execution. For example, you execute them from your code using the execution method which does not support multiqueries or DDLs.

Comment: I am using source command in 'mysql' MySQL Server binary.

Comment: The 3rd error message indicates the server is receiving "-" characters but your example SQL statements don't show any such characters. Have you really shown the exact SQL code you are executing, or is there more to it?

Comment: That '-' characters are from comment separators
There is something like:
```
---
--- Table ...
---

CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: I tested the code you showed, but there was no error. There must be some other content in your file that you haven't shown. There isn't enough information in your question to provide an answer, sorry.

Comment: That is strange... All other code is only for creating other tables. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I have just got an idea to manually, table-by-table, create `authors`, `categories`, and `reviews`. The only things I got as bad results were warnings about `INT(10)` being deprecated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).